# Eventbridge bus: can't receive messages on custom event bus?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I'm using AWS Eventbridge and I have the exact same rule on my default bus as on a custom bus. The target for both is an SQS queue. When I push an event I can see a message on my queue which is the target of the rule of my default bus.

I don't see anything on the queue of the rule of my custom bus. Also the metrics don't show an invocation. What am I doint wrong? I've created a custom bus.

I tried both without any policy as with the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "allow_account_to_put_events",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::my-account:root"
    },
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:xxx:my-account:event-bus/my-bus-name"
  }]
}
```

My event pattern:

```
  {
    "source": [
      "aws.ssm"
    ],
    "detail-type": [
      "Parameter Store Change"
    ],
    "detail": {
      "name": [
        "someparam"
      ],
      "operation": [
        "Update"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your rule on the custom bus is correct and detects your events?

Comment: Yes, I've added the event pattern too, and it both are using the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your custom bus will not receive any `"aws.ssm"` events. All `aws.*` are going to default bus only. The custom bus can only receive custom events from your application, e.g.:

```
    "source": [
      "myapp.test"
    ]
```

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html):

> When an AWS service in your account emits an event, it goes to your account’s **default** event bus.

Comment: so how can I pass an ssm update of a certain resource/param?

Comment: @DenCowboy Pass where? To the sqs?

Comment: to a custom bus. I want a custom bus because I need some special policy for it which I don't want to put on my default bus.

Comment: @DenCowboy A target on a default bus, can be a custom bus. So you can try that. For more complex filtering, you would have to use lambda as target first, and then publish events from lambda to a custom bus.

Comment: Thanks, I'll publish a custom event from my lambda to the bus

Comment: Thanks, took me hours wondering why events are not getting triggered... I feel like AWS should have disabled the AWS services event source when creating a rule under a custom event bus....